# Is there anything wrong with a random seed of 0, 1

Tags: random

Is there anything particularly wrong with a random seed of 0, 1... or any other small integer, when using Mersenne Twister?

(I definitely want a repeatable pseudorandom sequence hence not seeding from time() or such like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem whatsoever.

The point of seeding via a single integer is programmers's convenience:

- You don't need to remember the rules for admissible seeds ("need 55 numbers, not all even; need < 256 bytes; ...");
- You can (hopefully) easily get either different streams, or sequences which are at least far away from one another (some generators can prove this, not sure about MT); the seed is just (conceptually!) an index into a list of possible sequences.

The actual value of the seed is irrelevant -- 0 isn't more random than 1391202260 :)

Comment: Thanks.  The property of getting different streams (ideally decorrelated) - what is that called and which generators can prove this?  That would be useful to know.

Comment: No idea what it's called; some generators have it "by accident" (eg multiply with carry, lagged fibonacci), others are designed to have it, like block ciphers in counter mode (probably too slow). The paper "Random numbers: as easy as 1,2,3" includes a nice review and is quite readable.